# UIButton size with Autolayout at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have found several questions on this but I haven't found a solid answer on how to really do this, so I hope this isn't a duplicate just for not finding a concrete answer.

Here's my issue: I'm rewriting an old iOS app that has a tableview with custom cells, and inside each cell there's a button with a single color.
The width of the button is calculated at runtime to display each button's width being different for each cell, creating what looks like a side chart.

I want/need to do the same thing but I have my project already done with Autolayouts, and I need this to work on both iPhone and iPad so removing autolayout at this point will be kind of a pain.

Because of the autolayout, I have the layout of my cell with constrains and it looks fine when all cells are the same width, but I haven't figured out a way to make it change it's width at runtime.

Here's also another issue, from the questions I have found on SO.

This is what my cell looks like at runtime:

[image]

I need this button in the middle (the blue-ish thing) to stay in the middle of the team name and the value, and the values on the right have to remain in their same position (so not moving to the left if the bar is very small).

Any suggestion on this issue would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I might be overlooking some details, but couldn't you set the centre of your Button to the centre of the cell?
myButton.center = cell.center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the button both centerX and centerY constraints; that will keep it in the middle. Give it a fixed width, and make an IBOutlet to that constraint so you can update its constant value in code to modify the width of the bar. The team name label should have a constraint to the left edge, and the value label should have one to the right edge; that will keep them in place on all screen sizes.

As an example, this code in the table view controller,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@{@"name":@"One", @"value": @6094, @"width": @200}, @{@"name":@"Two", @"value": @210, @"width": @20}, @{@"name":@"Three", @"value": @7075, @"width": @250}, @{@"name":@"Four", @"value": @6648, @"width": @225}, @{@"name":@"Five", @"value": @2300, @"width": @100}, @{@"name":@"Six", @"value": @900, @"width": @50}];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.leftLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    cell.rightLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  self.theData[indexPath.row][@"value"]];
    cell.widthCon.constant = [self.theData[indexPath.row][@"width"] floatValue];
    return cell;
}
```

Gave this result,

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to do this in code though?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos You need to use constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant: to make the centering constraints. You can use that, or constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views: to make the constraints for the two labels. Why do you want to do it code anyway, it's easier to set them up in IB.

Comment: Because each button needs its own width at runtime, so one needs to have a width of 30, another a width of 200...and so on, and the value i have for that is an int so I need to make the relativity of the location be assigned by a specific number

Comment: @TooManyEduardos That has nothing to do whether you make the constraints in code or IB. As I said, you make an IBOutlet to the width constraint, and you would set the constant value of that constraint in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, the constrains are made in IB but I need to modify the width of the button at runtime. I used to do it with the button's frame size but now I believe I need to modify the existing constraints to make the button wider or thinner at runtime. Right?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Yes, that's correct. You do that by changing the constant value of that constraint.

Comment: Which parameter is that one from the line you suggested on the first comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76723/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-toomanyeduardos).

Comment: Give me about 30 mins and I'll be back for the chat. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm back and in the chat. Thank you for your help!